# keras model.fit accuracy not the same as model.evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

For a certain purpose, I want to explore the fitting limit of a single neuron. For binary classification, I believe a neuron can perfectly fit a rising edge or a falling edge. Therefore, I want to code to verify this situation. However, during the actual testing process, I encountered the following issues.

I am not sure why the training accuracy of the model is 1.0, but it does not reflect the same accuracy when testing on the training set using model.evaluate.

Here is the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
import random
from keras import layers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam


def random_seed(seed_num=1):
    np.random.seed(seed_num)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)
    random.seed(seed_num)


class CustomEarlyStopping(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super().__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        accuracy = logs["accuracy"]
        loss = logs['loss']
        if accuracy >= self.threshold:
            self.model.stop_training = True

# data init
x = np.arange(-20, 30, 0.1)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df.y = df.x.map(lambda x: 0 if x<10 else 1)
X_train = df.drop(columns='y')
y_train = df.y

# model
random_seed()
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=X_train.shape[-1]),
    layers.Normalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train, 
    batch_size=128,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[
        CustomEarlyStopping(1.0)
    ]
)
history_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

last_accuracy = history_df.accuracy.tolist()[-1]
predict_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)[-1]

print('last_accuracy', last_accuracy)           # 1.0
print('predict_accuracy', predict_accuracy)     # 0.9940000176429749
```

I attempted not to use early stopping and directly checked the results at different epochs, but many times, the values between the two were different. I don't understand this situation.

Comment: This has been commented many times here, you are comparing training accuracy (over batches while weights are changing) vs accuracy on the whole  training set (weights not changing). Of course they are different.

Comment: Your expression is quite peculiar. I naturally understand that the accuracy of the model changes with each epoch during training. My goal, however, is to stop the training when the accuracy reaches 1.0. Yet, why isn't the accuracy 1.0 during validation when the model has reached this level in training? According to your suggestion (you seem experienced), how should I modify the code to achieve this purpose?

Comment: ^ that's another question entirely

Comment: I'm also interested in the why. I tested it with `batch_size=600` and there was still a difference. I also compared the weights in `on_batch_end`, `on_batch_end` (both when it got to 1.0 acc) and after training, and they were the same, so no gradient step inbetween. With only one batch and one gradient step per epoch, there shouldn't be any more differences, should there?

Comment: I think I kown the reason about this. Because the log['loss'] is the last batch accuracy! Not all the datasets accuracy. So, it is easy to deal with this problem. Take all the datasets as validation data in model.fit,  and use logs['val_accuracy'] to check the accuracy. After some epochs, all the datasets accuracy will be 1.0

Comment: @mhenning I now have a slightly better understanding of the relationship between neurons and individual feature columns. However, when faced with datasets that require feature engineering, it seems I still don't have a good solution.╮(╯_╰)╭

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I set the `batch_size` bigger than the dataset. Then there is only one batch, which contains the whole dataset (in your case 500 samples).

Comment: I tried the approach you mentioned, and indeed there are differences in the results. When EarlyStopping stops the epoch, the model at this point cannot perfectly fit the data. It seems that the ideal model is from the current epoch - 1. Initially, when I realized there was bias in accuracy, I tried using a larger batch size.

Comment: However, considering that I often need to test x = np.arange(-20, 30, 0.1) >> x = np.arange(-20, 30, 0.01), there were too many code modifications required, so I didn't use this method later. I don't know the reason behind this. I attempted to find detailed descriptions about logs['accuracy'] on the TensorFlow official website but couldn't locate any.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this can fix the problem.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
import random
from keras import layers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam


def random_seed(seed_num=1):
    np.random.seed(seed_num)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)
    random.seed(seed_num)


class CustomEarlyStopping(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super().__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        accuracy = logs["val_accuracy"]
        if accuracy >= self.threshold:
            self.model.stop_training = True

# data init
x = np.arange(-20, 30, 0.1)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df.y = df.x.map(lambda x: 0 if x<10 else 1)
X_train = df.drop(columns='y')
y_train = df.y

# model
random_seed()
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=X_train.shape[-1]),
    layers.Normalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_train, y_train),
    batch_size=128,
    epochs=300,
    callbacks=[
        CustomEarlyStopping(1.0)
    ]
)
history_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history)

last_accuracy = history_df.accuracy.tolist()[-1]
predict_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)[-1]

print('last_accuracy', last_accuracy)           # 1.0
print('predict_accuracy', predict_accuracy)     # 1.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).